# codeigniter $this->dbutil->csv_from_result ignore last delimiter

Tags: php, codeigniter, csv

I am using the following function to export to CSV.

```
$this->dbutil->csv_from_result()
```

Unfortunately at the end of the line it prints delimiter, When I use CSV to import data again it takes it as a field with out key. example are here:

> "id", "time", "name",
>
> "1", "1400000000", "John",
>
> "2", "1400000000", "Matt",

Wondering if anybody can help with this.

Comment: I would like to get ride of the last delimiter. See the comma at the end of each line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use

`rtrim($string, ",");  // this will strip the comma from the end of the string`

Example :

```
$string = "abc" ; 

echo rtrim( $string , "c") ; 

It will echo ab
```

Comment: $out = rtrim($out); already added in "\system\database\DB_utility.php"